# Set number of rows for gnome-terminal or other emulators

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, stty

I'm aware there exists `stty`, which allows to set number of rows in a virtual console, such as tty1. However, this does not seem to work with gnome-terminal or xterm. The question therefore is, how would I limit number of rows in a terminal emulator regardless of the window size? In other words, if with `stty rows 20` in tty1 I can see output starting to roll up to 20th row (instead of default 34 on my machine), how would I achieve same thing with a terminal emulator?

Comment: relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4371/change-default-width-of-gnome-terminal-and-terminator-windows and https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/app-terminal-sizes.html.en

Answer (score 1):

@sebastian pointed to these as relevant, but they address only part of the problem:

- [Change default width of gnome-terminal and terminator windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4371/change-default-width-of-gnome-terminal-and-terminator-windows) (Ubuntu)
- [Terminal sizes](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/app-terminal-sizes.html.en) (Gnome)

Some of the discussion here is more relevant, but still not helpful:

- [Change the number of rows and columns in the TTY [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86967/change-the-number-of-rows-and-columns-in-the-tty)
- [How to change font-size, number of rows / columns on a terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/how-to-change-font-size-number-of-rows-columns-on-a-terminal)

When you use `stty` like this

```
stty rows 20
```

you are telling the operating system that your terminal has 20 rows.  That may be correct, but if it is not you will see unexpected behavior.  With *most* terminals, if you have something with 25 *real* lines and tell the system that you have only 20 lines, applications will continue to use the remaining 5 lines.

Linux is unusual here: you can reduce the number of lines shown in the virtual console with that `stty` command (which makes an interesting effect with a virtual machine).  Linux initializes the console to a *mode* which supports a given number of lines and columns.  The `stty` command tells the console I/O driver to use less of it.  A similar command to (attempt to) increase the size beyond the initialized mode limits fails.

The common feature with the first set of links is that there is a preferences dialog in some terminals which lets you select an initial window size.  That is (almost) the same as the Linux initialization of the *mode* for the terminal.  But:

- there is no mention of a method for changing the usual window size (within the initial limits), and
- there is no mention of a method to ensure that the window size limits remain the same.

The other links are even less relevant, since they are mainly a discussion (some details wrong...) of how to initialize the Linux console *mode*.

Back to the missing pieces:

- xterm has a utility [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) which (for many terminals) can change the window size.  If you type

  resize -s 20 80

  then xterm (and gnome-terminal) will change their window to 20 lines (and 80 columns).  Depending on how xterm is compiled, you may have to select the *Allow Window Ops* menu entry (since the feature is considered a vulnerability by some).
- preventing your window from being manually resized is harder.  If you do not do this, your 20-line resizing is lost by the first time someone (accidentally) resizes the window.

Many window managers allow you to customize individual windows, removing the *resize handles*. Here are a few links discussing that topic:

- [Disable the 'Resize Window Grippers' in Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal](http://blog.patshead.com/2011/04/disable-the-resize-window-grippers-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal.html)
- [Getting rid of self-resizing windows in Ubuntu Linux 12.04](http://earlruby.org/2012/04/getting-rid-of-self-resizing-windows-in-ubuntu-linux-12-04/)
- [Prevent GNOME from expanding windows](https://superuser.com/questions/599561/prevent-gnome-from-expanding-windows)

For setting the **initial** size of an xterm window, you would use either the [**`-geometry`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#X-Toolkit-Options:-geometry) option or the related [**`geometry`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:geometry) resource.  That uses the X Toolkit, whose settings are described in the [***X(7)***](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.7.0/doc/X.7.html) manual page.  The section for [*geometry specification*](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.7.0/doc/X.7.html#sect6) is a good place to continue reading.

Comment: I'm trying to find documentation on XTerm, and it's not easy. For example, I prefer 25 rows by 80 columns as the default. It's easy enough to Allow Window Ops and run the resize. But how can I configure .Xresources or /etc/X11/app-defaults/Xterm to make this happen from the get-go?