# STTY: How can I set rows/columns to its supported maximum?

Tags: stty

I would like some 83(cols)x40(rows) size on my **TTY**, so:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ stty size
30 90
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ stty cols 83 rows 40
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ stty size
30 83
```

As can be seen in my example, cols=40 is not supported on my computer.
So I must try:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ stty rows 39
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ stty rows 38
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ stty rows 37
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ stty rows 36
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$
```

...until I success.

Is there any way to directly set stty to **its maximum**?
Maybe something like:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ stty rows max
```

Comment: I have never heard of this kind of limit! What kind of terminal are you running under? `xterm`? `gnome-terminal`? ssh? I cannot reproduce this. For me, `stty rows` accepts arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: @Celada, just `Ctrl+Alt+Fn`. A single text mode terminal, not GUI.

Comment: OP is referring to a Linux **console** quirk, as discussed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157405/set-number-of-rows-for-gnome-terminal-or-other-emulators).

Answer (score 5):

`stty` is the wrong tool for this job.  You want `setupcon`, which lets you choose a graphical font size to be displayed on the frame buffer console.  The font size, combined with the resolution of the monitor, determines how many rows and columns you can see.  `stty` is for telling a remote kernel you are accessing via a serial terminal what the actual size of your terminal display is.

Answer (score 1):

See my functions from this post for a solution using terminal codes: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283206

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in *[Set number of rows for gnome-terminal or other emulators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157405/set-number-of-rows-for-gnome-terminal-or-other-emulators)*:

> Linux is unusual here: you can reduce the number of lines shown in the virtual console with that stty command (which makes an interesting effect with a virtual machine). Linux initializes the console to a mode which supports a given number of lines and columns. The `stty` command tells the console I/O driver to use less of it. A similar command to (attempt to) increase the size beyond the initialized mode limits fails.

Answer (score 0):

IDK about a maximum but try:

**# stty columns 83 rows 40**

*I actually use 160 x 55 myself and it works like a champ*