# Resize the screen resolution in cli sessions under debian

Tags: debian, vmware

Lot of times I work with various debian virtual machine directly in the vmware console.

This is what it looks like

[image]

It is possible to resize the monitor screen like from 800x600 to 1024x768 or greater in order to have more space?

Thanks

Comment: `gnu-screen` is about the `screen` command , not about displaying a (virtualized) video screen.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is what is called a Linux "console" and represents what you might see if you had a physical machine with an attached screen & keyboard. Hypervisors (such as VMware) provide "remote console" emulation so that you can access the console for troubleshooting. It looks like you can customize the remote console behaviour and "stretch" the console to fill the view. You can also resize the resolution to "fit guest" and both probably achieve the same result.

> Here are the VMware docs: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Remote-Console/12.0/com.vmware.vmrc.vra.doc/GUID-FDE3AE4D-07A9-427E-ADC7-7CFF6495FF2B.html

Evidently there's a preferences menu attached to the console where you can set your VMRC (virtual machine remote console) flags to "Stretch Mode"

**Reconfiguring the VM to use a different kernel size**

The OP asks the following in the comments:

> I found a command called `stty`, calling `stty size` it prints `37 100`, if I try to set the size like `stty rows 40` (or every other number bigger than 37) it says: `stty: 'standard input': Invalid argument` and the same with `stty cols 101` or more. If I go below the 37 and 100 it shrinks the size correctly, so I'm wondering why I can't go over 37 and 100?

See this answer for an alternative approach re: `setupcon` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199760/102266

**NB.** I strenuously suggest, however, that you avoid this altogether. Connect via SSH and resize your SSH client. Leave the console for troubleshooting and who cares about the size. That's what everyone else does and, depending on your usecase, it is probably what you should do too.

Comment: Worth noting that this will not increase resolution, but stretch the image/text to a larger one.

Comment: Indeed I was trying to find a command able to switch resolution of the monitor like the hardware one. I noted that on physical installation the console tends to enlarge to the maximum available space (eg. if I'm in a 1920x1080) monitor it become very large allowing a lot of typing. Was hoping a command like resize-screen 1920x1080 but I'm not sure if it exists.

Comment: I found a command called `stty`, calling `stty size` it prints `37 100`, if I try to set the size like `stty rows 40` (or every other number bigger than 37) it says: `stty: 'standard input': Invalid argument` and the same with `stty cols 101` or more. If I go below the 37 and 100 it shrinks the size correctly, so I'm wondering why I can't go over 37 and 100?

Comment: I also tried to search for something like an hidden config for vmware in order to setup the basic resolution bigger than 800x600 but it seems I can't...