# Hot-changing font-size, number of rows / columns on a text terminal

Tags: linux, console, resolution

This question comes from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/how-to-change-font-size-number-of-rows-columns-on-a-terminal) other.

I have no X-Windows installed in my system.
I just simply would like to **change rows/columns** in a text console (terminal) **without rebooting**.
The desired behavior would be the one we find in the classic DOS/Windows command:

```
mode col,rows
```

Is it possible?

A generic answer would be fine. If not possible, at least Ubuntu or Debian would be preferred.

Comment: See here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86967/change-the-number-of-rows-and-columns-in-the-tty

Comment: You can do this in `/etc/console-setup`. But the linux kernel's terminal emulator - the console terminal - doesn't support much. I think it can do a limited history buffer nowadays, but it leaves a lot to be desired - specifically in that it supports only bitmapped fonts. If you are resolved to remain at the console - which is fine - consider replacing the standard getty/console setup with something that will handle xfonts and session management and ptys - consider [`kmscon`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148627/52934).